# error in server side of pygame video streaming

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, video-streaming, python-imaging-library

i am new to pygame and trying to stream video over pygame.
my client side is working fine but in sender side i get error and sender and client are not connecting.

my sender code is:

```
import socket,os
from PIL import *
import pygame,sys
import pygame.camera
from pygame.locals import *
#Create server:
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(("10.3.100.207",5000))
server.listen(5)
#Start Pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320,240))
cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0",(320,240),"RGB")
cam.start()
#Send data
while True:
   s,add = server.accept()
   print "Connected from",add
   image = cam.get_image()
   screen.blit(image,(0,0))
   data = cam.get_raw()
   s.sendall(data)
   pygame.display.update()
#Interupt
for event in pygame.event.get():
   if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
   sys.exit()
```

but when i run this code i get this following error

```
siplab@siplab-OptiPlex-9020:~$ python tut1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tut1.py", line 9, in <module>
server.bind(("10.3.100.207",5000))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```